# Regular expression to mask email except the three characters before the domain

Tags: java, regex, email

I am trying to mask email address in the following different ways.

1. Mask all characters except first three and the ones follows the @ symbol.
   This expression works fine.

   (?<=.{3}).(?=[^@]*?@)

   abcdefgh@gmail.com -> abc*****@gmail.com
2. Mask all characters except last three before @ symbol.

   Example : abcdefgh@gmail.com -> *****fgh@gmail.com

   I am not sure how to check for @ and do reverse match.

Can someone throw pointers on this?

Comment: What if email is `ok@example.com`? Should it show unmasked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do a positive lookahead:

```
.(?=.*...@)
```

See the online [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZotvZK/3)

- `.` - Any character other than newline.
- `(?=.*...@)` - Positive lookahead for zero or more characters other than newline followed by three characters other than newline and `@`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^\s@]` matching a non whitespace char except an @. Then assert what is on the right is that negated character class 3 times followed by matching the @ sign.

In the replacement use `*`

```
[^\s@](?=[^@\s]*[^@\s]{3}@)
```

- `[^\s@]` Negated character class, match a non whitespace char except `@`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[^@\s]*` Match 0+ times a non whitespace char except `@`
  - `[^@\s]{3}` Match 3 times a non whitespace char except `@`
  - `@` Match the @
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0v5F5V/1)

---

If there can be only a single @ in the email address, you could for example make use of a finite quantifier in the positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=(?<!\S)[^\s@]{0,1000})[^\s@](?=[^@\s]*[^@\s]{3}@[^\s@]+\.[a-z]{2,}(?!\S))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gt5IF6/1)